# How to redirect to logon page when session State time out is completed in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application where I am implementing sessionTimeout like:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="2"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And in authentication:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="1" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

After the session has expired (2 mins), I need to redirect to the logon page, but the redirection doesn't occur.

How can I change the code so that it will redirect?

Comment: Please check the below link. It may help you.

[Login page url][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356982/how-to-redirect-to-a-dynamic-login-url-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One way is that 
In case of Session Expire, in every action you have to check its session and if it is null then redirect to Login page.

**But this is very hectic method**
To over come this you need to create your own `ActionFilterAttribute` which will do this, you just need to add this attribute in every action method.

Here is the Class which overrides ActionFilterAttribute.

```
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

            // check if session is supported
            CurrentCustomer objCurrentCustomer = new CurrentCustomer();
            objCurrentCustomer = ((CurrentCustomer)SessionStore.GetSessionValue(SessionStore.Customer));
            if (objCurrentCustomer == null)
            {
                // check if a new session id was generated
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Users/Login");
                return;
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Then in action just add this attribute like so:

```
[SessionExpire]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return Index();
}
```

This will do you work.

Comment: Basically i need to create the class you defined in each of my controller and each action method i need to give **ActionFilterAttribute** and for index method i need to give **[SessionExpire]**. Is that so

Comment: no you just need to create that class in your app_start only one and add that attribute to the action

Comment: U mean in the global.asax.cs page i need to add this code in the Application_Start() function

Comment: ya OnActionExecuting add this method

Comment: No not yet. what is CurrentCustomer there what namespace should i include for that. And can i get a pop up window intimating the user that the session is timed out

Comment: yar current cust is my session object , here add your session object.
namespace is already written in global.asax so no need .
pop thing is you have to add this , i have just given the logic for session expire check

Comment: Add one App_Start Folder either , then add one class file,then add namespace - 'yourprojectName.App_Start' then in that copy paste my code  and use that attribute

Comment: I also have a problem with the Customer part, i have make a class in the App_Start And included the correct namespace, but it wont regognize customer? Any idea?

Comment: somebody could you explain me What is the class CurrentCustomer and SessionStore I have error in this.

Comment: As user1006544 has stated, you have to implement CurrentCustomer and SessionStore by yourself.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417197/asp-net-mvc-session-usage ?

Comment: Excellent Solution Buddy. 1000+ for you.

Comment: Where i need to set "objCurrentCustomer" to Null?

Comment: can someone tell me why it is not redirecting to the specified url ..could the url be wrong? its not crashing any more but stays on the same page

Comment: The code is not clear. I can't understand what CurrentCustomer nor SessionStore are.

Comment: The code is checking if the session is active by trying to place an object into that session. That object, is CurrentCustomer. Thus, if the session active, the object can be inserted, and the code passes. Using SessionExpireFilterAttribute is a great idea. but I disagree with the need for the CurrentCustomer object.

Answer (score 33):

I discover very simple way to redirect Login Page When session end in MVC. I have already tested it and this works without problems.

In short, I catch session end in _Layout 1 minute before and make redirection.

I try to explain everything step by step.

If we want to session end 30 minute after and redirect to loginPage see this steps:

1. Change the web config like this (set 31 minute):

   ```xml
    <system.web>
       <sessionState timeout="31"></sessionState>
    </system.web>
   ```
2. Add this JavaScript in `_Layout` (when session end 1 minute before this code makes redirect, it makes count time after user last action, not first visit on site)

   ```html
   <script>
       //session end 
       var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout- 1;

       var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;
       setTimeout('SessionEnd()', sTimeout);

       function SessionEnd() {
           window.location = "/Account/LogOff";
       }
   </script>
   ```
3. Here is my LogOff Action, which makes only LogOff and redirect LoginIn Page

   ```cs
   public ActionResult LogOff()
   {
       Session["User"] = null; //it's my session variable
       Session.Clear();
       Session.Abandon();
       FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); //you write this when you use FormsAuthentication
       return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
   }
   ```

I hope this is a very useful code for you.

Comment: Probably want to [reset the `setTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout) on any AJAX calls as the user could continue to interact with the form and keep the session alive on the back end

Comment: This will redirect to login even if user is still working

Answer (score 6):

**There is a generic solution:**

Lets say you have a controller named Admin where you put content for authorized users.

Then, you can override the **`Initialize` or `OnAuthorization` methods of Admin controller** and write redirect to login page logic on session timeout in these methods as described:

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //lets say you set session value to a positive integer
        AdminLoginType = Convert.ToInt32(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["AdminLoginType"]);
        if (AdminLoginType == 0)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/login");
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
```

Comment: Where should Session["AdminLoginType"] be initialized??

Comment: @Dr.MAF Inside Login Page that belong to an other controller

Comment: Saved My day. Thanks