# how to redirect to login page when session in expired in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the situation -i'm calling controller throught ajax in javascript script which return partial view.now when session end the login page view is loaded in div but i want to redirect to login page not to load login view in div.

Comment: Try `return RedirectToAction("actionname","controllername");`

Comment: still it return view of login page :(

Comment: post your view and controller code

Comment: Try this `return View("~/Home/myview.cshtml");` give the path of the view to which you want to redirect

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier if you use forms authentication. However, this link will help you : http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2007/09/05/115173.aspx

Comment: Bro the ajax call to controller in my situation was supposed to return view to div and when session used to be expired it was redirected to login page and that was consider as return view to div.actually session was working but due to ajax call it was being view of login page returned to div.is there any way to redirect the whole web page from controller and redirecting to login page?

Answer (score 1):

Try refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873398/how-to-redirect-to-logon-page-when-session-state-time-out-is-completed-in-asp-ne/13874154#13874154)

It will help to create one attribute for login which will help to check every time when the action of any controller is called and perform the task accordingly.