# Redirect to Login on session expiry in MVC

Tags: session, model-view-controller

How  I can redirect to Login.cshtml from session_end of Global.asax on session expiry.

Response.redirect() not working there.

Please comment on it.

Comment: use  RedirectToAction("Actionname", "Controllername");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to logon page when session State time out is completed in asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873398/how-to-redirect-to-logon-page-when-session-state-time-out-is-completed-in-asp-ne)

Answer (score 0):

try this may be you will able to check the session is in process or expire

[Check this](http://findnerd.com/list/view/ASP-NET-MVC-How-to-check-session-timeout-and-redirect-to-login-page-/11664/)

Answer is given here

[check also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873398/how-to-redirect-to-logon-page-when-session-state-time-out-is-completed-in-asp-ne)

### Here is the Class which overrides ActionFilterAttribute.

```
  public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        // check  sessions here
        if( HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null ) 
        {
           filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login/Index");
           return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
  }
```

### Then in action just add this attribute as shown :

```
  [SessionExpire]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return Index();
   }
```

### Or Just add attribute only one time as :

```
       [SessionExpire]
       public class LoginController : Controller
       {
         public ActionResult Index()
          {
            return Index();
          }
       }
```

Comment: Nikhil Thanks,Where I Can put SessionExpireAttribute  class?    Global.asax.cs or some where else?

Comment: its a action filter and you have to apply it on controller or any controller action method

Comment: In global.asax.cs